# Erro no banco de dados Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, android-recyclerview

Olá, eu "criei" um aplicativo com registro de usuário e login, após a a tela de login que vem o problema, o sistema para logar está funcionando, começou a dar problema depois que criei uma tela com uma RecyclerView para cadastrar algumas coisas no banco de dados e elas serem exibidas, quando logo o aplicativo já da erro e fecha. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu serei muito grato. Segue abaixo o código das telas e log de erro.

Código da classe que adiciona no BD

```
public class Adicionar extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Senhas senhas;
    private View layout;
    private EditText origem;
    private EditText nome;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText senha;

    private Button salvar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_adicionar);

        senhas = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("key");

        layout = findViewById(R.id.ConsLayout);


        origem = findViewById(R.id.txtOrigemAd);
        nome = findViewById(R.id.txtNomeAd);
        email = findViewById(R.id.txtEmailAd);
        senha = findViewById(R.id.txtSenhaAd);

        origem.setText(senhas.getOrigem());
        nome.setText(senhas.getNome());
        email.setText(senhas.getEmail());
        senha.setText(senhas.getSenha());



        salvar = findViewById(R.id.btnSalvar);
        salvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                senhas.setOrigem(origem.getText().toString());
                senhas.setNome(nome.getText().toString());
                senhas.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
                senhas.setSenha(senha.getText().toString());

                /*if (senhas.getNome().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(Adicionar.this, "É necessário um nome para salvar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }*/



                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("key", senhas);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Classe do BD

```
public class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    /*BANCO DE DADOS*/

    //Nome do banco de dados
    public static final String BANCO_DADOS = "keyssword.db";

    //Versão do banco de dados
    public static final int VERSAO_BANCODADOS = 1;

    //Nome da tabela usuarios
    public static final String TABELA_USUARIOS = "usuarios";

    //********Campos da tabela de usuários********//

    //Coluna de ID, Chave primária
    public static final String ID = "id";

    //Coluna de nome de usuário
    public static final String NOME_USUARIO = "nomeusuario";

    //Coluna E-mail
    public static final String EMAIL = "email";

    //Coluna senha
    public static final String SENHA = "senha";


    //********Campos da tabela de senhas********//

    //Nome da tabela usuarios
    public static final String TABELA_LISTASENHAS = "listasenhas";

    //Coluna de ID, Chave primária
    public static final String IID = "id";

    //Coluna de nome de onde a senha é
    public static final String NOME_ORIGEM = "origem";

    //Coluna de nome de usuário
    public static final String NOME_USER = "usuario";

    //Coluna E-mail
    public static final String EMAIL_ = "email";

    //Coluna senha
    public static final String SENHA_ = "senha";

    //SQL para criar tabela de usuários
    public static final String SQL_TABELA_USUARIOS = " CREATE TABLE " + TABELA_USUARIOS
            + " ( " + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + NOME_USUARIO + " TEXT, "
            + EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + SENHA + " TEXT" + " ) ";


    //SQL para criar tabela de usuários
    public static final String SQL_TABELA_LISTASENHAS = " CREATE TABLE " + TABELA_LISTASENHAS
            + " ( " + IID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + NOME_ORIGEM + " TEXT, "
            + NOME_USER + " TEXT, "
            + EMAIL_ + " TEXT, "
            + SENHA_ + " TEXT " + " ) ";


    public SqliteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, BANCO_DADOS, null, VERSAO_BANCODADOS);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){

        //Cria uma tabela quando o onCreate é chamado
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_TABELA_USUARIOS);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_TABELA_LISTASENHAS);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int il) {

        //Descarta a tabela para criar uma nova,
        // se a versão do banco de dados for maior
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABELA_USUARIOS);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABELA_LISTASENHAS);
    }


    public List<Senhas>getList(String order){
        List<Senhas> senhas = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursorsenha = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABELA_LISTASENHAS + " ORDER BY origem " +
                order + ";", null);

        while (cursorsenha.moveToFirst()){
            Senhas c = new Senhas();

            c.setId(cursorsenha.getLong(cursorsenha.getColumnIndex("id")));
            c.setOrigem(cursorsenha.getString(cursorsenha.getColumnIndex("origem")));
            c.setNome(cursorsenha.getString(cursorsenha.getColumnIndex("nome")));
            c.setEmail(cursorsenha.getString(cursorsenha.getColumnIndex("email")));
            c.setSenha(cursorsenha.getString(cursorsenha.getColumnIndex("senha")));

            senhas.add(c);
        }

        cursorsenha.close();

        return senhas;

    }

    public void inserirSenha(Senhas c){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("origem", c.getOrigem());
        values.put("nome", c.getNome());
        values.put("email", c.getEmail());
        values.put("senha", c.getSenha());

        getWritableDatabase().insert(TABELA_LISTASENHAS, null, values);
    }

    public void alteraSenha(Senhas c){
        ContentValues valuessenha = new ContentValues();

        valuessenha.put("id", c.getId());
        valuessenha.put("origem", c.getOrigem());
        valuessenha.put("nome", c.getNome());
        valuessenha.put("email", c.getEmail());
        valuessenha.put("senha", c.getSenha());

        String[] idParaSerAlterado = {c.getId().toString()};
        getWritableDatabase().update(TABELA_LISTASENHAS, valuessenha, "id=?", idParaSerAlterado);
    }


    public void apagarSenha(Senhas c){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String[] args = {c.getId().toString()};
        db.delete(TABELA_LISTASENHAS, "id=?", args);
    }



    public Usuarios ValidaUsuario(Usuarios usuario) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        //Seleciona a tabela
        Cursor cursor = db.query(/*Seleciona a tabela*/ TABELA_USUARIOS,
                new String[]{ID, NOME_USUARIO, EMAIL, SENHA},/*Seleciona as colunas para a query*/
                EMAIL + "=?",
                new String[]{usuario.email},
                null,null,null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getCount()>0){
            Usuarios user = new Usuarios(cursor.getString(0),
                    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getString(3));

            if (usuario.senha.equalsIgnoreCase(user.senha)){
                return user;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    //Esse método é responsavel por adicionar usuários à tabela
    public void addUser(Usuarios usuario) {

        //Abre o banco de dados para gravação
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //Cria os valores de conteúdo para inserir
        ContentValues inserir = new ContentValues();

        //Coloca o nome de usuário em values
        inserir.put(NOME_USUARIO, usuario.nomeUsuario);

        //Coloca o emial em values
        inserir.put(EMAIL, usuario.email);

        //Coloca a senha em values
        inserir.put(SENHA, usuario.senha);

        //Inserir linha
        long todo_id = db.insert(TABELA_USUARIOS, null, inserir);
    }



    public boolean ValidaEmail(String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABELA_USUARIOS,
                new String[]{ID, NOME_USUARIO,EMAIL,SENHA},
                EMAIL + "+?",
                new String[] {email},
                null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getCount()>0){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Classe do layout do RecyclerView

```
public class Lista extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SqliteHelper helper;
    private RecyclerView SenhasRecy;
    private Adapter adapter;
    private List<Senhas> listaSenhas;
    private final int REQUEST_NEW = 1;
    private final int REQUEST_ALTER = 2;
    private String order = "ASC";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Lista.this, Adicionar.class);
                i.putExtra("key", new Senhas());
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_NEW);
            }
        });

        helper = new SqliteHelper(this);
        listaSenhas = helper.getList(order);
        SenhasRecy = findViewById(R.id.SenhasRecy);
        SenhasRecy.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linear = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linear.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        SenhasRecy.setLayoutManager(linear);
        adapter = new Adapter(listaSenhas);
        SenhasRecy.setAdapter(adapter);

        SenhasRecy.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItem(getApplicationContext(),
            new RecyclerItem.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position){
                        abrirOpcoes(listaSenhas.get(position));
            }
        }));


    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_NEW && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Senhas Senhas = data.getParcelableExtra("key");
            helper.inserirSenha(Senhas);
            listaSenhas = helper.getList(order);
            adapter = new Adapter(listaSenhas);
            SenhasRecy.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else if(requestCode == REQUEST_ALTER && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Senhas Senhas = data.getParcelableExtra("key");
            helper.alteraSenha(Senhas);
            listaSenhas = helper.getList(order);
            adapter = new Adapter(listaSenhas);
            SenhasRecy.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }


    private void abrirOpcoes(final Senhas senhas){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(senhas.getNome());
        builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]{"Editar", "Excluir"},
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        switch (i){
                            case 0:
                                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Lista.this, Adicionar.class);
                                intent1.putExtra("contato", senhas);
                                startActivityForResult(intent1, REQUEST_ALTER);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                listaSenhas.remove(senhas);
                                helper.apagarSenha(senhas);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        builder.create().show();
    }

    /*@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.order_az) {
            order = "ASC";
        } else if(id == R.id.order_za){
            order = "DESC";
        }

        listaSenhas = helper.getList(order);
        adapter = new Adapter(listaSenhas);
        SenhasRecy.setAdapter(adapter);

        return true;
    }*/

}
```

Log de erro

```
QLiteLog: (1) table listasenhas has no column named nome
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting origem= senha= nome= email=teste
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table listasenhas has no column named nome (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO listasenhas(origem,senha,nome,email) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1472)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
        at com.gnd.keyssword.SQl.SqliteHelper.inserirSenha(SqliteHelper.java:137)
        at com.gnd.keyssword.Lista.onActivityResult(Lista.java:80)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4320)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4367)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Log do novo erro

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gnd.keyssword, PID: 4805
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 55380616 byte allocation with 6291456 free bytes and 46MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 561962912, growth limit 603979776
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3139)
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3109)
        at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:275)
        at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:249)
        at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:241)
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:467)
        at com.gnd.keyssword.SQl.SqliteHelper.getList(SqliteHelper.java:120)
        at com.gnd.keyssword.Lista.onActivityResult(Lista.java:81)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4320)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4367)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Acho que o erro está bem claro. Você está tentando inserir em uma coluna que não existe. Mais especificamente, inserir na coluna `nome`, que no seu script foi declarado como `NOME_USER = "usuario";`. Você esqueceu de utilizar as constantes nos métodos `inserirSenha` e `alteraSenha`. ;)

Comment: Ainda sou iniciante em BD, poderia ser mais específico por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o erro informa: Você está tentando inserir um valor em uma coluna que não existe no banco, ou seja, está tentando inserir um valor na coluna **"nome"**, coluna não existente na sua tabela **listasenhas** do banco de dados.

Nos métodos inserirSenha e alteraSenha, tente substituir "nome" por "usuario", desta forma:

```
  public void inserirSenha(Senhas c){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("origem", c.getOrigem());
        values.put("usuario", c.getNome());
        values.put("email", c.getEmail());
        values.put("senha", c.getSenha());

        getWritableDatabase().insert(TABELA_LISTASENHAS, null, values);
    }

    public void alteraSenha(Senhas c){
        ContentValues valuessenha = new ContentValues();

        valuessenha.put("id", c.getId());
        valuessenha.put("origem", c.getOrigem());
        valuessenha.put("usuario", c.getNome());
        valuessenha.put("email", c.getEmail());
        valuessenha.put("senha", c.getSenha());

        String[] idParaSerAlterado = {c.getId().toString()};
        getWritableDatabase().update(TABELA_LISTASENHAS, valuessenha, "id=?", idParaSerAlterado);
    }
```

**OU**

```
    public void inserirSenha(Senhas c){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(NOME_ORIGEM, c.getOrigem());
        values.put(NOME_USER, c.getNome());
        values.put(EMAIL_, c.getEmail());
        values.put(SENHA_, c.getSenha());

        getWritableDatabase().insert(TABELA_LISTASENHAS, null, values);
    }

    public void alteraSenha(Senhas c){
        ContentValues valuessenha = new ContentValues();

        valuessenha.put(IID , c.getId());
        valuessenha.put(NOME_ORIGEM , c.getOrigem());
        valuessenha.put(NOME_USER , c.getNome());
        valuessenha.put(EMAIL_ , c.getEmail());
        valuessenha.put(SENHA_ , c.getSenha());

        String[] idParaSerAlterado = {c.getId().toString()};
        getWritableDatabase().update(TABELA_LISTASENHAS, valuessenha, "id=?", idParaSerAlterado);
    }
```

Comment: Agora está me retornando outro erro

Comment: Já adicionei o novo log

Comment: Já desinstalei e instalei de novo três vez e já testei em outro Emulador.

Comment: De uma olhada nesse material https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio

Comment: Vou olhar sim, obrigado.

Comment: Dei uma olhada, desativei todas as imagens do meu projeto e continua o erro

Comment: Explique um pouco mais sobre o problema. Quando acontece, etc. Se possível poste o log completo aqui.

Comment: É um app com registro e login, quando loga é redirecionado para uma tela onde tem uma RecyclerView, e um botão flutuante para adicionar novo registro, esse botão redireciona para outra tela onde é feito o registro contendo Origem, nome, email e senha, quando aperta o botão para salvar essas informações no banco de dados é que dá o problema, a tela fica preta e logo o app para e da esse erro. O log todo não tem como pois ultrapassa o limite de caracteres.

Comment: Qual método esse botão de salvar chama? Esse método está na pergunta ?

Comment: Ta no código do "Código da classe que adiciona no BD" é o btnSalvar.